# Generics and unchecked errors

Tags: java, generics

I have a class like:

```
  class BSTNode<K extends Comparable, V> {
    K key;
    BSTNode(K key, V value) { ... }
  }
```

Then I am using

```
node.key.compareTo(root.key) >= 0
```

Where `node` and `root` are `BSTNode`. In that line, I am getting an unchecked error. Why?

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type Comparable
      } else if (node.key.compareTo(root.key) >= 0) { // new node >= root
                                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
1 warning
```

In my understanding, as defined in `BSTNode`, `K` should extend/implement `Comparable`. So `node.key.compareTo(root.key)` should be OK?

Comment: Can you show us the variable declarations of `node` and `root`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Comparable` is also generified. Try the following:

```
class BSTNode<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> { ... }
```

Also, make sure to use the proper types in your declarations:

```
// will cause the warning
BSTNode root = new BSTNode<Integer, Integer>(1, 1);
// will NOT cause the warning
BSTNode<Integer, Integer> root = new BSTNode<Integer, Integer>(1, 1);
```

Comment: for best results use `K extends Comparable<? super K>>`

Answer (score 2):

The class should implement a generic version of Comparable. In your case `Comparable<K>`:

```
class BSTNode<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
   K key;
   BSTNode(K key, V value) {}
}
```

Comment: for best results use `K extends Comparable<? super K>>`